# Increasing hex value with given data

Tags: c++, qt, checksum

I need to compare given text data with checkSumCalculator method and I try to send the data with command method. I find and changed the code according to my own needs. But I dont understand some parts.
How can 0x00 hex char will be increase with given data? and how/what is the point of comparing check_data with 0xFF? How to extract (check_data & 0xFF) from 0x100 hex? I am very confused.

```
void Widget::command()
{
    std::string txt = "<DONE:8022ff";
    unsigned char check_sum = checkSumCalculator(&txt[0], txt.size());

    QString reply= QString::fromStdString(txt) + QString("%1>").arg(check_sum, 2, 16, 
QChar('0')); 
    emit finished(replyMessage, true);
}

static unsigned char checkSumCalculator(void *data, int length)
{
    unsigned char check_data = 0x00;
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
        check_data+= ((unsigned char*)data)[i];

    check_data = (0x100 - (check_data & 0xFF)) & 0xFF;
    return check_data;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`checkSumCalculator` starts by adding together all the values of the buffer in `data`. Because the type of `data` is `unsigned char`, this sum is done modulo 0x100 (256), 1 more than the maximum value an `unsigned char` can handle (0xFF = 255); the value is said to "wrap around" (`(unsigned char) (0xFF + 1)` = 256) is again `0`).

These two lines:

```
    check_data = (0x100 - (check_data & 0xFF)) & 0xFF;
    return check_data;
```

are really more complicated than it's needed. All that would be needed would be:

```
    return -check_data;
```

That is, at the end it negates the value. Because the arithmetic is modulo 256, this is essentially the same as flipping the bits and adding 1 (-check_data = ~check_data + 1). This is instead implemented in a more convoluted way:

- `check_data & 0xFF` doesn't do much, because it's a bitwise AND with all the possible bits that can be set on an `unsigned char`. The value is promoted to an unsigned int (due to C's default integer promotions) where all the bits higher than the lower 8 are necessarily 0. So this is the same as `(unsigned int)check_data`. Ultimately, this promotion has no bearing on the result.
- Subtracting from 0x100 is the same as `-check_data`, as far as the lower 8 bits are concerned (which what we end up caring about).
- The final `& 0xFF` is also redundant because even though the expression was promoted to unsigned int, it will converted as an unsigned char by returning.